# Pure CSS dropdown menu with collapse/hide option

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, responsive

I am trying to insert a pure CSS dropdown responsive menu to a website. Menu is simple with some extra style coding. But what bothers me is that when opening a dropdown label, the dropdown submenu appears but it doesn't go away if I click anywhere else or on another label in the menu. I am trying to make that when opening dropdown submenu after clicking anywhere else with mouse or finger (on touchscreen) this submenu will collapse back. Tried with :focus but nothing seems to work.

I could sure use some help.
Thank you.
And here is the code:

```css
.nav-bar {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar__label {
    color: #505050;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: inherit;
}

.nav-bar__label::after,
.nav-bar__sub-label::after {
    content: " +";
}

.nav-bar__label,
.nav-bar__sub-label {
    cursor: pointer;
 
}

.nav-bar__list {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-bar__list,
[id^="toggle"] {
    display: none;

}

[id^="toggle"]:checked + .nav-bar__list {
    display: block;
}

    /* DRUGI LIST */

.nav-bar__list2 {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}

.nav-bar__list2,
[id^="toggle"] {
    display: none;
}

[id^="toggle"]:checked + .nav-bar__list2 {
    display: block;
}

    /* KONEC DRUGEGA LISTA */


.nav-bar__list-item {
    display: block;
}

.nav-bar__link,
.nav-bar__sub-label {
    color: #505050;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__link,
.nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__sub-label {
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
}

.nav-bar__link:hover,
.nav-bar__link:active,
.nav-bar__sub-label:hover {
    background: #cc0000;
 color: #fff;
}


@media all and (min-width : 992px) {
    .nav-bar > .nav-bar__label {
        display: none;
    }

    .nav-bar > .nav-bar__list {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-bar > .nav-bar__list > .nav-bar__list-item {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list {
        position: absolute;
    }
 
 /* DRUGI LIST */
 
    .nav-bar > .nav-bar__list2 {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav-bar > .nav-bar__list2 > .nav-bar__list-item {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list2 {
        position: absolute;
    }

    .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__link,
    .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__list-item .nav-bar__sub-label {
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
    <html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Responsive Menu</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive-menu.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="nav-bar">
        <label for="toggle" class="nav-bar__label">Menu</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" class="nav-bar__toggle">
        <ul class="nav-bar__list">
            <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                <label for="toggle-sub-1" class="nav-bar__sub-label">Menu Item 4</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="toggle-sub-1" class="nav-bar__toggle">
                <ul class="nav-bar__list2">
                    <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 4.1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 4.2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 4.3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-bar__list-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu Item 5</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use radio buttons instead of checkboxes, so that you can group them together by name, so that only one of them can be checked at a time ...

Comment: Example where clicking on the open label or on another label will close the submenu: https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/b9380ep7/ - working on one where clicking anywhere will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution using hovers**:

Leverages the focus-like state of `:hover` in mobile browsers - the trick is to put the hover on an ancestor that will always be considered "hovered" when anything anywhere in the children are as well. Very clean and semantically correct. Check out the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/mzL2yorv/6/)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

p {
  padding: 1.6em 0 0;
}

.pretendthisisthebody {
  padding: 50px 10px 0;
}

#hideholder {
  display: none;
}

.radionav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  width: 100%;
}

.radionav>div {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.radionav div,
.radionav a {
  color: #505050;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
}

.radionav li:hover>div{
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.radionav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

.radionav ul ul a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.radionav input,
.radionav .closer,
.radionav ul,
.radionav input:checked ~ .opener {
  display: none;
}

.radionav:hover>ul,
.radionav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.radionav div::after {
  content: " +";
}

@media all and (min-width: 481px) {
  .radionav>div {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .radionav>ul
  {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .radionav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .radionav a,
  .radionav div {
    width: auto;
  }
  .radionav li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .radionav a:hover {
    background: #cc0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .radionav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .radionav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .radionav ul ul a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .radionav li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .radionav div::after {
    content: "";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pretendthisisthebody">
  <nav class="radionav">
    <div>Menu</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 0</a></li>
      <li>
        <div>Menu item 1</div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Just a link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Just a longer link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Just a link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
      <li>
        <div>Menu item 4</div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Just a link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Just a longer link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#fail">Just a link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <h1>Clicking in the body outside the menu will hide it</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit aliquam suscipit. Vivamus ac mi tellus. Donec vulputate sem eu justo ornare, at mattis augue tempor. Nullam fringilla odio lobortis bibendum lobortis. Fusce condimentum ultricies
    nulla, non posuere sem vestibulum nec. Duis rhoncus velit lobortis odio interdum, quis aliquam ex dapibus. Quisque hendrerit pellentesque turpis non pretium. Nam ante metus, tempus quis tortor lacinia, efficitur ullamcorper erat. Sed at aliquet
    nisi, ac congue massa.</p>
  <p>Mauris est odio, tempor in ex ac, cursus iaculis ex. Etiam eu dapibus dolor. Quisque sodales mollis neque fringilla maximus. Praesent malesuada vitae elit eu congue. Mauris fringilla maximus arcu sit amet tempor. Nam sagittis lectus massa, eu viverra
    enim congue a. Nunc ultrices sapien nec enim auctor, ac placerat velit posuere. Donec velit ex, consectetur vitae sapien eget, eleifend maximus sem. Sed placerat nibh mi, eget fermentum justo ultrices nec.</p>
</div>
```

**Earlier solutions**:
This one uses a simple radio-button fueled collapsable menu, but wraps everything in a `<label>` tag to support "blur-like" behavior. The simple version is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/0ytvmdyn/1/) and the multi-level version with similar styles to the OP is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/freer4/x1yeqe5d/2/)

Comment: This looks good but this is not a responsive menu. It doesn't also collapse together when opening on mobile phone or tablet. I have tried, maybe I need to insert some other code to make it collapsable and so responsive.

Comment: @Tadey responsive is a matter of CSS - just apply your styles. This works for me on GalaxyS6 Chrome - what phone/tablet are you targeting?

Comment: @Tadey updated - this is probably much closer to what you want.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Now I have made it, with your help. Thank you very very much! Very useful.

Comment: @Tadey don't forget to vote and accept if this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

And this is my final menu with my css. Thank you @Randy Hall

```css
<style type="text/css"><!--
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #FFF;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

p {
  padding: 1.6em 0 0;
}

.pretendthisisthebody {
  padding: 50px 10px 0;
}

#hideholder {
  display: none;
}
.radionav {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #007de7;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight:400;
}

.radionav>div {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.radionav div,
.radionav a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.1s all ease-in-out;
}

.radionav li:hover>div,
.radionav a:hover {
  background: #cc0000;
  color: #fff;
}

.radionav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #007de7;
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.radionav ul ul a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.radionav input,
.radionav .closer,
.radionav ul,
.radionav input:checked ~ .opener {
  display: none;
}

.radionav:hover>ul,
.radionav li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

.radionav div::after {
  content: " +";
}

@media all and (min-width: 481px) {
  .radionav>div {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .radionav>ul
  {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .radionav>ul>li {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .radionav a,
  .radionav div {
    width: auto;
  }
  .radionav li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .radionav ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
  }
  .radionav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  .radionav ul ul a {
    padding-left: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .radionav li:hover>ul {
    display: block;
  }
  .radionav div::after {
    content: "";
  }
} 

--></style>
```

```html
<div class="pretendthisisthebody">

<!-- MODRI MENI -->
<nav class="radionav">
    <div>Meni</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li>
        <div>Main menu 2</div>
        <ul>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 1 long</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 5 - extra long item</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 10</a></li>        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Main menu 3</a></li>
      <li>
        <div>Main manu 4</div>
        <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" class="nav-bar__link">Menu item 2 - with very long title</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Ouyeah menu</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact item</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
<!-- KONEC MODREGA MENIJA -->
<h1>Clicking in the body outside the menu will hide it</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur blandit aliquam suscipit. Vivamus ac mi tellus. Donec vulputate sem eu justo ornare, at mattis augue tempor. Nullam fringilla odio lobortis bibendum lobortis. Fusce condimentum ultricies
    nulla, non posuere sem vestibulum nec. Duis rhoncus velit lobortis odio interdum, quis aliquam ex dapibus. Quisque hendrerit pellentesque turpis non pretium. Nam ante metus, tempus quis tortor lacinia, efficitur ullamcorper erat. Sed at aliquet
    nisi, ac congue massa.</p>
  <p>Mauris est odio, tempor in ex ac, cursus iaculis ex. Etiam eu dapibus dolor. Quisque sodales mollis neque fringilla maximus. Praesent malesuada vitae elit eu congue. Mauris fringilla maximus arcu sit amet tempor. Nam sagittis lectus massa, eu viverra
    enim congue a. Nunc ultrices sapien nec enim auctor, ac placerat velit posuere. Donec velit ex, consectetur vitae sapien eget, eleifend maximus sem. Sed placerat nibh mi, eget fermentum justo ultrices nec.</p>
</div>
```